# Convert Series of List to DataFrame using generator expression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*s* is a Series object:

```
>>> s
0     [2010, 1]
1     [2011, 5]
2    [2012, 10]
dtype: object
```

Then I came across the following, which converts *s* to a DataFrame using generator expression.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(i for i in s)
>>> df
      0   1
0  2010   1
1  2011   5
2  2012  10
```

Is there any explanation as to why this works? I do not understand why this works.

Comment: read doc [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) - `"data : ... or list-like objects"`. So you can use generator.

Comment: @furas You can't always do so. For  example, passing a `zip` or `map` objects results in a TypeError.

Comment: @furas the doc states: `"data: Dict can contain... or list-like objects"`. There's no dictionary involved.

Comment: It's probably not updated. You can pass lists, lists of lists, tuples, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is why it's working. Behind the scene the `Generator` is converted back to a `list`. Here is a chunk of the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L236-L6142).

```
if isinstance(data, types.GeneratorType):
  data = list(data)
```

And it works the same with a `list`.

```
# Creating a list
l = [1,2,3]
# Using the generator
df1 = pd.DataFrame(i for i in l)
# Using the list
df2 = pd.DataFrame(l)
df1.equals(df2)
# True
```

Comment: I realised that the docs did not mention that you can create a dataframe from a list.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most straightforward solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [[2010, 1],[2011, 5],[2012, 10]]})

df[['a1', 'a2']] = df['a'].apply(pd.Series)
```